# std::atomic lock free for class with composition

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have the following unit test which seems to suggest that std::atomic is lock free for a struct with std::string or a class with inheritance, but not a class with composition.

I was expecting std::string might require lock due to heap allocation etc. I was also expecting that composition and inheritance are close enough in terms of how the memory is laid out etc, that their lock-freeness will be the same.

Any suggestions why my expectation does not hold true? I am on ubuntu 14.04 and gcc 4.9.

```
TEST(Test, PODWithString) {
  struct POD {int a; std::string b;};
  std::atomic<POD> pod({1,"2"});
  EXPECT_TRUE(pod.is_lock_free());
}

TEST(Test, INHERITANCE) {
  struct B {B(int x): x(x) {} int x; };                                                                                        
  struct D : public B {D(int x, int a): B(x),a(a) {} int a; };                                                                 
  std::atomic<D> d(D(1,2));
  EXPECT_TRUE(d.is_lock_free());                                                                                               
}

TEST(Test, PODNested) {
  struct POD {int x; int y;};
  struct PODNested {int a; POD b;};
  std::atomic<PODNested> pod_nested({1, {2,3}});
  EXPECT_FALSE(pod_nested.is_lock_free());
}
```

Comment: How are you running this exactly? `std::atomic<POD>` in your first example is ill-formed (also `POD` is not a POD).

Comment: Clang tells you your mistake: "_Atomic cannot be applied to type 'POD' which is not trivially copyable"

Comment: From your remark "I was expecting std::string might require lock due to heap allocation" I have the feeling that you are deeply misunderstanding what atomic operations are about.

Comment: [Example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/8yCgzVh9M3brtOfq). Make sure to use things like `-march=native` to enable cmpxchg16b etc. Whether an object can be accessed lock-freely depends on its layout. E.g. in my example, four ints are lockfree, but three are not. You need the padding for lock-free access to consecutive objects.

Comment: @barry ub, technically.

Comment: the code compiles and passes the tests on gcc4.9 with -latomic. I guess gcc has some bugs about PODWithString? Thanks @KerrekSB for the example, I guess it shows there is not really clear rule about the lock-free-ness as a function of whether the class is inherited or composed. Instead, lock-free-ness depends on the memory layout, architecture etc and only a working compiler can tell you if something is lock-free?

Comment: @KerrekSB: Please never ship software compiled with `-march=native`. Even defaulting to it in Makefile is annoying and dangerous. I had some bad experiences lately. Build it, put it in Docker, run it in the cloud, and get illegal instruction crashes.

Comment: @bill: Kind of. The only type for which it is required that all objects are lock-free is `std::atomic_flag`. For real-world lock-free applications what you really care about is usually whether you can get a lock-free double-word CAS, or at least an exchange perhaps.